# asp.net webforms create user wizard with new steps

Tags: asp.net

i am using the create user wizard, and it works great with the default 2 steps
1 - enter all the info
2 - the complete button

step 1 has some extra data in it, and I hook into the created user event in order to kick off some other processes.

I want to create a middle step for the user to confirm what they have captured in the previous step.

to do this i add a new step with the wizard, this gives me a   button.

But the problem is that step 1 still creats all the user information in my db, i only want that to happen after step 2

Comment: Actually you place your creation code after the step 2. I do not understand where did you stack.

Comment: mine is - i.e creating in my table, but the ASPnet_users table it gets created already